# Ingress-nginx configuration required to add a Security Group to an NLB at creation time

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller, aws-nlb

I have an *AWS EKS* version **1.26** cluster up and hosting a Java application. I am managing ingress configurations by running a *ingress-nginx* controller version **4.5.2**. Through *ingress-nginx* I have configured an external NLB with the following configuration *yaml* file and *helm* command:

**external-controller.yaml**

```
defaultBackend:
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"

controller:
  replicaCount: 2
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: "linux"
  ingressClassResource:
    name: nginx-ext
    enabled: true
    default: false
    controllerValue: "example.com/ingress-nginx-ext"
  ingressClass: nginx-ext
  ingressClassByName: true
  service:
    # Enable the external LB
    external:
      enabled: true
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "false"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internet-facing"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

**Helm command**

```
 helm install "ext-nginx-ingress-controller" ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
 --namespace "ext-ingress" \
 --version 4.5.2 \
 -f "external-controller.yaml"
```

Executing this helm command results in the creation of a internet-facing NLB, which is exactly what I want. That said what is not to my liking is that in the AWS console if I check the *Security* tab under this NLB I just created I see the following message:

> No security group associated
>
> Because this load balancer was created without a security group, these settings can't  be changed. To utilize security groups, ensure that one is specified during creation of the load balancer.

What do I need to add to **external-controller.yaml** to get a security groups associated to my NLB at creation time?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I can't even create a NLB with precreated SG with annotations
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-security-groups: sg-<>